# meteor fs.collection 500 error after insert image

Tags: meteor

I'am trying to make work image upload in meteor using FS.Collection2 library https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

I manage to upload pictures and show them, but after I insert an image I get the following server error (I only insert, I don't update anything)

```
 Exception while invoking method '/cfs.images.filerecord/update' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to '/cfs.images.filerecord/update'
```

This is my code:

insert:

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

collection:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images")]
});


if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Images.allow({
        insert: function (fileID, doc) {
            return true;
        },
        update: function (fileID, doc) {
            return true;
        },
        remove: function(userId, doc) {
            return false;
        },
        download: function (fileID, doc) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

FS Packages versions:

```
cfs:filesystem              0.1.1  
cfs:standard-packages       0.5.3
```

Thanks  hope you can point me in the right direction

I added screen captures of the error.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this on your meteor app, and tell me if works,

First, for better declarations of Collections on the `/lib/collections.js folder`, use this.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images")]
});

if(Meteor.isClient) {
 Meteor.subscribe('Images');
 }
```

Also on meteor console, `meteor remove autopublish insecure`, and with this you have all collection safe, and also the first thing meteor loads it the `/lib`, folder so the collection now are available on both client/server

now on the `/server/collections.js`

```
Meteor.publish('Images', function(){
      return Images.find();
   });
Images.allow({
insert: function(userId, doc) { return true; },
update: function(userId,doc) { return true; },
remove: function(userId,doc) { return false; },
download: function(userId, doc) {return true;},
});
```

Now on `/client/insertingImages.html` , use some simple example

```
  <template name="example">
    <input id="addImage" type="file">
    <button type="submit" id="loadImage"> Click to add Image</button>
    </template>
```

now on    `/client/insertingImages.js`

```
Template.example.events({
  'click #loadImage' : function(template,event){
     var file = $('#addImage').get(0).files[0],
         metadataText = "this is some cool metadata text on the image";
         fsFile = new FS.File(file);
         fsFile.metadata = {textFile:metadataText}
     //Some authentication,(if not file selected cannot upload anything)
     if(file === undefined){
         alert("SORRY YOU NEED TO UPLOAD AN IMAGE TO CONTINUE");
        } else{
          Images.insert(fsFile,function(err,succes){
            if(err){
              console.log(err.reason);
              } else{
               console.log(succes); //this should return the fsFile, or the Id of fsFile
               }
           }
        }
  }
 })
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: Hi Etjana, thank so much for the reply (I paste your code exactly as you said), it behaves exactly the same way. uploads and save the picture but gives a server error after the insertion. I pasted couple of screen captures of the error

Comment: Remove `userId,doc` arguments on the `allow` seems like problem come from the server code, and its complaining about not all `arguments` got checked, try removing the 2 arguments

Comment: Well, I fix it, I remove the audit-argument-checks packet there was some incompatibility issues. But thanks for the response !! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have not figured out how to do it, then execute the following command in the console in your project directory:

```
 meteor remove audit-argument-checks
```

This will fix the error.